# Inconsistent new file line delimiter in PDSOE with OpenEdge

Tags: newline, openedge

I'm using Progress developer studio with OpenEdge 11.7.3.

In Window > Preferences > Workspace, I have "New text file line delimiter" setup to Other(Unix).
In project level (Project > Properties > Resource), I see "Inherited from container" automatically set to Unix.
With this setup, I encountered in inconsistent behavior.

File created from File > New > File uses Unix LF as line delimiter only, which is expected.

However, when creating from File > New > ABL Procedure (or ABL Include, ABL Class, etc), all end up with CRLF as line delimiter.  Anyone know why?  Anything can be done about it?

I found that if I go to project level, I use "Other"(and select unix) instead of "Inherited from container", then all files use LF only.  But, that will have to do manually, and for all projects!

All I need is a way to set this up at environment level only and work for all new files, no project level setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the same behavior (OpenEdge 12.2), to me it looks like a bug which you should consider reporting to Progress Tech Support.

However, if you use the [AnyEdit tools](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) plugin for Eclipse, upon saving the file all linefeeds are made consistent. As a bonus, trailing whitespace can also be purged.

Comment: I will definitely try Progress tech support and see what they say then.  And thanks for suggesting the plugin.  Trailing whitespace is also something my team is looking at too.

Comment: Alternatively you could consider OEDT. It's not free, but it does provide some pretty useful additional functionality to PDSOE. In fact a lot of the newer features in PDSOE of late are inspired by OEDT.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess I'd say it was because of the templates used to create the new file.

I've seen similar behaviour with tabs (I prefer spaces) being added when using the menu to add a method.

You should log a big with tech support.

Comment: When project linefeed is set explicitly (instead of inherit) the templates respect the setting,

Comment: I thought about template too.  However, since switching to Other(Unix) works, it doesn't look like template is the root cause to me.  Will definitely try Progress tech support and see what they say.  Thanks!